Multicast communication in a rootless docker setup
I would like to run gerbera (DLNA server) as docker container on my Arch server. As I'm not that experienced I wanted to run the container in a rootless docker setup.
I got the container running and the TCP communication works as I can access the gerbera web UI and I can browse the database and play single songs in the browser. The problem is that the DLNA server is not available in my UPnP controller like BubbleUPnP or Upplay. As this should work over UDP prot 1900 by means of multicast communication (SSDP) I assume that this is currently the problem.
It works when I start the container with sudo, but that's what I wanted to avoid. I created a custom docker network with the bridge driver but I read that multicast is a bit tricky. I also tried to use socat and configure iptables but to no avail. Probably because I do not really know how to configure this properly.
So my question would basically be: how can I forward the multicast communication from the container to my local network?
docker network:
docker network create --subnet=192.168.178.0/24 dlna 

docker container:
docker run --name gerb --net=dlna --ip=<ip> -p 49494:49494 -p 1900:1900/udp -d -v /path/to/music:/mnt/content:ro -v ~/.config/gerbera.xml:/var/run/gerbera/config.xml gerbera/gerbera:latest

